# d3.js updated rect keeps previous one

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've searched a lot but my javascript knowledge is limited to get the solution and to understand the solutions that I found.

I've created a D3.js graph that work fine.
It receives values from a json object and draw it with color change according to value.

Here is the code for D3 :

```
// Graphique D3.js
var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
    // .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>temp:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.temp + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

var dataJson = [
  { id: 0 ,timee:"0h00" , temp:1    },
  { id: 1 ,timee:"0h30" , temp:0    },
  { id: 2 ,timee:"1h00" , temp:0.5  },
  { id: 3 ,timee:"1h30" , temp:1    },
  { id: 4 ,timee:"2h00" , temp:1.5  },
  { id: 5 ,timee:"2h30" , temp:2    },
  { id: 6 ,timee:"3h00" , temp:2.5  },
  { id: 7 ,timee:"3h30" , temp:3    },
  { id: 8 ,timee:"4h00" , temp:3.5  },
  { id: 9 ,timee:"4h30" , temp:4    },
  { id:10 ,timee:"5h00" , temp:4.5  },
  { id:11 ,timee:"5h30" , temp:5    },
  { id:12 ,timee:"6h00" , temp:5.5  },
  { id:13 ,timee:"6h30" , temp:6    },
  { id:14 ,timee:"7h00" , temp:6.5  },
  { id:15 ,timee:"7h30" , temp:7    },
  { id:16 ,timee:"8h00" , temp:7.5  },
  { id:17 ,timee:"8h30" , temp:8    },
  { id:18 ,timee:"9h00" , temp:8.5  },
  { id:19 ,timee:"9h30" , temp:9    },
  { id:20 ,timee:"10h00", temp:10   },
  { id:21 ,timee:"10h30", temp:11   },
  { id:22 ,timee:"11h00", temp:12   },
  { id:23 ,timee:"11h30", temp:13   },
  { id:24 ,timee:"12h00", temp:14   },
  { id:25 ,timee:"12h30", temp:15   },
  { id:26 ,timee:"13h00", temp:16   },
  { id:27 ,timee:"13h30", temp:17   },
  { id:28 ,timee:"14h00", temp:18   },
  { id:29 ,timee:"14h30", temp:19   },
  { id:30 ,timee:"15h00", temp:20   },
  { id:31 ,timee:"15h30", temp:21   },
  { id:32 ,timee:"16h00", temp:22   },
  { id:33 ,timee:"16h30", temp:23   },
  { id:34 ,timee:"17h00", temp:24   },
  { id:35 ,timee:"17h30", temp:25   },
  { id:36 ,timee:"18h00", temp:25.5 },
  { id:37 ,timee:"18h30", temp:8    },
  { id:38 ,timee:"19h00", temp:21   },
  { id:39 ,timee:"19h30", temp:19   },
  { id:40 ,timee:"20h00", temp:20   },
  { id:41 ,timee:"20h30", temp:12   },
  { id:42 ,timee:"21h00", temp:25.5 },
  { id:43 ,timee:"21h30", temp:4    },
  { id:44 ,timee:"22h00", temp:0    },
  { id:45 ,timee:"22h30", temp:7    },
  { id:46 ,timee:"23h00", temp:18   },
  { id:47 ,timee:"23h30", temp:8    }
]

// The following code was contained in the callback function.
x.domain(dataJson.map(function(d) { return d.timee; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(dataJson, function(d) { return d.temp; })]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("temp");

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(dataJson)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.timee); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.temp); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.temp); })
    // Nuance de couleur de fond des barres :
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      if(d.temp > 18){
        return "rgb(" + (d.temp * 10) + ", 0 , 5)";
      }else if(d.temp > 12 && d.temp <= 18){
        return "rgb( " + (d.temp * 10) + ", 0, " + (d.temp * 10) + ")";
      }else{
        return "rgb( 5, 0, " + (d.temp * 10) + ")";
      }
     })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataJson)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
    return d;
    })
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataJson.length) + 5;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4) + 15;
   });

function type(d) {
  d.temp = +d.temp;
  return d;
}
```

Then I use an input type="number" to change in real time the graph with updGraph function 
1 input for each value, this one is for 0h00 value :

```
<input type="number" onInput="updtGraph(0,this.value);" id="tmpInp0" class="tmpInp" value="18" min="0" max="25.5" step="0.5">
```

Here is updtGraph(0,this.value), (and setTemp(id, newTemp) function used by updtgraph function) :

```
function setTemp(id, newTemp) {
  for (var i=0; i<dataJson.length; i++) {
    if (dataJson[i].id === id) {
      dataJson[i].temp = newTemp;
      return;
    }
  }
}

function updtGraph(id, newTemp){
  var svg = d3.select("svg").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  setTemp(id, newTemp);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(dataJson)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.timee); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.temp); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.temp); })
          // Nuance de couleur de fond des barres :
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            if(d.temp > 18){
              return "rgb(" + (d.temp * 10) + ", 0 , 5)";
            }else if(d.temp > 12 && d.temp <= 18){
              return "rgb( " + (d.temp * 10) + ", 0, " + (d.temp * 10) + ")";
            }else{
              return "rgb( 5, 0, " + (d.temp * 10) + ")";
            }
           })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
}
```

It works fine, if I change the value with input, D3 is updated :

value : 1 [image]

value : 19 [image]

But the problem is if I enter a value lower than the previous one, I stille have the old value printed behind the new one.

value 5 :

[image]

The new value is printed correctly (value : 5 colored in dark blue)
The previous value (value : 19 colored in red) is still shown but I want it to disapear.

How can I do this ?

Thanks a lot for help and sorry not to use JSfiddle that I can't make working with my code.

SOLVED : __________________________________________________________________

I found a solution to update the graph each time I changes settings by simply deleting the graph container :

```
document.getElementById("graph").innerHTML = '';
setTemp(id, newTemp);
createD3();
```

→ D3 graph is deleted
I have changed the code creating the graph by putting it in a function : createD3()
and then I update the new json value and create a new graph createD3().

Is is certainly slower than just editing the bar that has been changed but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, d3 will not remove elements that are no longer in the dataset. You'll have to use [`d3.selection.exit`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#exit) and write code to remove the elements that are no longer needed. I've included a simple example below, based on your `updtGraph` function:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(dataJson);
bars.enter().append("rect")... //put your remaining original code here
bars.exit().remove(); //removes all elements from the screen that have "exited" the data-set
```

Comment: Thank you for help but I don't get no change, certainly because of my code ^^. I dont understand how to remove bar or bars. I've written this in the edit function : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nonoseki/gukmukwu/6/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to help more without seeing a working copy on JSFiddle or a similar site. If you could get that working, I can certainly take a look at it and see what's going on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help anyway. If you want to have a look, I uploaded my files here [files](http://dl.free.fr/hUskISEPi). The button to edit called "update" is useless (it was for my first tests), and the first input can edit the graph (input just on the right of 00h00).

Comment: I found a solution by deleting completely the graph and creating a new one with updated values. Have a look at my first post, and thanks for help you gave me !